# JavaScript Login Username & Password

Tags: javascript

I am making a website for a school project, and in it, there is a login page. Right now, there is only 1 login username and password. How can I have TWO username and TWO passwords? I have tried the else if, but it didn't work. Any ideas? The code for the login is below.
Thanks

```js
function check(form) {
  if (form.userid.value == "admin" && form.pwd.value == "noahgrocery") {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect Password or Username")
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Login to Noah Grocery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="index.html" class="a">Home</a>
  <a href="contactus.html" class="a">Contact Us!</a>
  <a href="products.html" class="a">Products</a>
  <a href="cart.html">
    <img src="https://codehs.com/uploads/d1091610e3a63fb99a6d5608b94a0fa8" width="50px" height="50px" style="float:right; margin-right: 15px">
  </a>
  <a href="userlogin.html">
    <img src="https://codehs.com/uploads/a4a800a1e73c30e0f37382731c3b1234" width="50px" height="50px" style="float:right; margin-right: 15px; background-color: white;">
  </a>
  <center><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1NKWr5CjLNa7tYtO8a49xQ_mcWzMoWGg_" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></center>

  <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="admin.html">
    <table width="20%" align="center">

      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
          <center>
            <font size=4><b>Login to Noah Grocery</b></font>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size=25 name="userid"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="Password" size=25 name="pwd"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="Reset"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form)" value="Login"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to use `||` (OR). Be careful with operator precedence: it should be `(A && B) || (C && D)`.

Comment: "I have tried the else if, but it didn't work." can you show us the code for that `else if` that failed?

Comment: All I did was add another row with the if(password and user) with else if instead of if.

Comment: @caTS How would I do that? Would A and B be the username?

Comment: Say the logic in English: If the username is A and the password is B, or if the username is C and the password is D, return true.

Comment: Could you send me that example using the code above? The username has to be in the form.userid.value, and I can't have a username and password in the username.

Comment: @RandomCoder16 look at what caTS wrote about `(A && B) || (C && D )`. imvain2 just posted an answer using that logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, as you are new and its a school project I just kept it simple.

I wrapped each user/pass in () and added || as or between the two groups and added them on separate lines to make it obvious.

```js
function check(form) {

  if (form.userid.value == "admin" && form.pwd.value == "noahgrocery"){
      form.action = "#";
      return true;
  }
  else if(form.userid.value == "admin2" && form.pwd.value == "noahgrocery2"){
      form.action = "#";
      return true;
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect Password or Username")
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="a">Home</a>
<a href="contactus.html" class="a">Contact Us!</a>
<a href="products.html" class="a">Products</a>
<a href="cart.html">
  <img src="https://codehs.com/uploads/d1091610e3a63fb99a6d5608b94a0fa8" width="50px" height="50px" style="float:right; margin-right: 15px">
</a>
<a href="userlogin.html">
  <img src="https://codehs.com/uploads/a4a800a1e73c30e0f37382731c3b1234" width="50px" height="50px" style="float:right; margin-right: 15px; background-color: white;">
</a>
<center><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1NKWr5CjLNa7tYtO8a49xQ_mcWzMoWGg_" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></center>

<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="admin.html">
  <table width="20%" align="center">

    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <center>
          <font size=4><b>Login to Noah Grocery</b></font>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input type="text" size=25 name="userid"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type="Password" size=25 name="pwd"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="Reset"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form)" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have one login page with the 2 usernames and passwords each leading to a separate page? I would like to have one lead to one page, and the other lead to a different page.

Comment: @RandomCoder16 I updated my answer. Basically just have **else ifs**. Now there are multiple ways to do this and other ways are far more efficient, but as you are new and this is for school I don't want to use features that you may not have been taught yet.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I just remove the form action at the top of the HTML form code now?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is just for fun and you are not doing authorization authentication this way.

but make an array of password objects.

```
const users =
  [
    {userid: 'admin', password: 'noahgrocery' }, 
    {userid: 'joe', password: 'secret' }
  ];
```

then use find to see if it exists.

```
const user = users.find(
  x => x.userid === form.userid.value &&
       x.password === form.password.value);
```

then just check and see if  user exists.